# getopt in C++ command line arguments with the options

Tags: c++

I am writing a simple program to have `-d` with a parameter along with the other arguments

I want them run with aa.cc with the following options

- `aa -d 123 param1 param2` or
- `aa param1 param2 -d 123`

I have written the code in the following way

```
    /* sample */

    char *level:
    while ((ch = getopt(argc, argv, "d:")) != EOF) {
        switch(ch) {
        case 'd':
            level = optarg;    
            debug = TRUE;
            break;
        default:
            usage();
            /*NOTREACHED*/
        }
    }
```

It is working fine when given as
`aa -d 123 param1 param2` but not 
when given as 
`aa param1 param2 -d 123`.

Can anyone please suggest how we can achieve that?

Comment: Note that `getopt()` is documented to return `-1` rather than `EOF` after the last option is processed.  The POSIX standard header for `getopt()` is `<unistd.h>` and that does not define `EOF`, so the definition of `getopt()` was changed (quite a while ago now) to decouple it from the `<stdio.h>` header.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're using the GNU version of [`getopt()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html), option arguments (such as `-d 123`) must precede non-option arguments (such as `param1` and `param2`).  (See POSIX ['Utility Conventions'](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html).)

If you're using [GNU `getopt()`](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html), it will scan the entire argument list (up to but not including a `--` argument), processing options found after non-options, unless the `POSIXLY_CORRECT` environment variable is set (in which case it behaves like POSIX `getopt()`, of course).

If you're not using GNU `getopt()`, you have to live with options before non-options, or switch to GNU `getopt()`, or write your own.